# connection refused error on virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox, centos7

Hello Stackoverflow experts, I'm facing a connection refused, while trying to install a package using **yum** I switch the command to **curl** to overrule any issue with yum, The **Centos7** VM is running on **oracle-virtual** box with the bridge Adaptor

```
[root@centos7 ~]# curl -vv -k https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/repodata/repomd.xml
* About to connect() to yum.dockerproject.org port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 54.192.189.202...
* Connection refused
* Failed connect to yum.dockerproject.org:443; Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to yum.dockerproject.org:443; Connection refused
```

**The ping works**

```
[root@centos7 ~]# ping yum.dockerproject.org
PING yum.dockerproject.org (54.192.189.202) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from server-54-192-189-202.maa3.r.cloudfront.net (54.192.189.202): icmp_seq=1 ttl=244 time=10.0 ms
^C
--- yum.dockerproject.org ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.016/10.016/10.016/0.000 ms
```

**The Firewall is stopped in the Virtual VM**

```
[root@centos7 ~]# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
```

*I have stopped the Firewall in the Host VM also*

```
[root@Host-Lnx ~]# /etc/init.d/iptables status 
Table: filter
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

After taking all the necessary check on conenctivity still getting **connection refused**

Comment: Do you get the same faillure with "wget" ?

Comment: [root@centos7~]# wget https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/repodata/repomd.xml
--2017-04-18 09:05:28--  https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/7/repodata/repomd.xml
Resolving yum.dockerproject.org (yum.dockerproject.org)... 54.192.189.202
Connecting to yum.dockerproject.org (yum.dockerproject.org)|54.192.189.202|:443... failed: Connection refused.
[root@centos7-postgres-2 ~]#

Comment: That's weired, I tried with my Centos Server 7.2 and it is working, try an http site if it works try curl with one of these options:
 --ssl
 --ssl-reqd
 --sslv2 
 --sslv3 
 --ssl-allow-beast
 --tlsv1
 --tlsv1.0
 --tlsv1.1
 --tlsv1.2